# How to insert Javascript code in a Ruby injection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, textfield, code-injection

I have 2 text fields. One is for the input of a member's id, and the other is the output of the member's name.

When I type a member's id in the first field and the action `onblur` is triggered, I would like to show the member's name in the other field.

This is my Javascript function:

```
function show_name(){
          id = document.getElementById('id_member').value;
          field_name = document.getElementById("name_member");

          field_name.value = "<%= Member.find().nom %>";
      }
```

In the method `Member.find()` I would like to send the value of the variable `id` that I've declared at the beginning. Example:

```
field_name.value = "<%= Member.find(*Javascript "ID" variable value*).nom %>";
```

How can I insert that value into my Ruby injection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is run on the client, ruby is run on the server.   You can't pass a javascript variable into the ruby code, unless you make a new request to the server.

Your options are to reload the whole page with a new query, use ajax to make a new query and do something with the result, or to download all possible Members into the page ahead of time and have javascript pull it out of the page somehow.